# Passing a parameter into an object in curly brackets during instantiation in C#

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

When you pass an variable into an object during instantiation, such as in

```
SomeObject newObject = new SomeObject() { SomeString = "String goes here" };
```

Will the variable SomeString be accessible in the constructor or will it be assigned afterwards? If I needed to use it in the constructor, would it work or would I need to pass it through as a parameter using

```
new SomeObject("String goes here");
```

Comment: Minor aside: If you set properties on instantiation like this, you don't need the `()`, and also you can mix constructor parameters with the `{ .. }` syntax.

Comment: @Flynn1179 whats the difference of not having () and having ()

Comment: None; they're just not necessary on parameterless constructors if you use an initializer like this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> will the variable SomeString be accessible in the constructor, or will it be assigned afterwards?

It will be assigned afterwards.

```
SomeObject newObject = new SomeObject() { SomeString = "String goes here" };
```

is roughly equivalent/syntactic sugar to:

```
SomeObject temp = new SomeObject();
temp.SomeString = "String goes here";
SomeObject newObject = temp;
```

Comment: @lukas, yes there is a `temp`. In real world it is not called `temp` but the name is specifically generated by the C# compiler to avoid any name clashes. The temporary object is used by the compiler to ensure that your reference can only ever refer to a properly initialized object. So for example the variable isn't set to the fully-initialized object until all the properties are set, so if an exception is thrown, the constructed object is lost even if the exception is caught (the variable will remain null or whatever value it had before).

Comment: @darin-dimitrov does that mean then that it would be more efficient to just use SomeObject newObject = new SomeObject(); SomeString - "String goes here"; ?

Answer (score 4):

It will be assigned afterwards in the first case. **NOTE: This requires there to be a parameterless constructor**, which will exist by default, unless you define a parameterized constructor. In that case you must define both constructors explicitly.

For more detail you can look at details on [Object Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx).

Comment: You can do this if there's no parameterless destructor. The syntax is `SomeObject newObject = new SomeObject(Object constructorParam) { SomeString = "String goes here" };`

Comment: I believe you meant constructor (not destructor as it's not relevant for the question). That aside, yes you can have only a parameterized constructor and still pass the string through as a property, but then you are required to pass an object to the constructor, which the OP is not doing or asking about. The question is whether or not the string being passed via a property can be accessed in the constructor, which it cannot, unless it is passed in directly.

Comment: Yeah, how the heck did I miss that one.. sorry! Anyway, to clarify, I meant the general case, not this specific question, but you're right in this case of course.